# Set different color for ProgressBar drawable but same XML drawable

Tags: android, progress-bar

I am having following xml file.I want to make the shape of progress bar with some background color.
But my each progressBar will contain different background color. But i want to do it in only one xml file which contain shape and different color so that i can reduce xml files in drawable.

**Custom_horizontal_bar:**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
            <!--<corners android:radius="25dip" />-->
            <gradient android:startColor="#ffffff" android:centerColor="#ffffff"
                android:centerY="0.75" android:endColor="#ffffff" android:angle="90" />
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#6B8E23" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <!--<corners android:radius="25dip" />-->
                <gradient android:startColor="#4d94ff" android:endColor="#4d94ff"
                    android:angle="90" />
                <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#6B8E23" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**ProgressBar:**

```
<ProgressBar
              android:id="@+id/myProgress2"

                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

                android:max="100"
                android:progress="60"
                android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_horizontal_bar"
                android:secondaryProgress="0" />
```

Kindly give any suggestion.

Comment: No other option!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

1.

```
LayerDrawable layerDrawable = (LayerDrawable) getResources()
    .getDrawable(R.drawable.Custom_horizontal_bar);
GradientDrawable gradientDrawable = (GradientDrawable) layerDrawable
    .findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.progress);
gradientDrawable.setColor(...);

ProgressBar myProgress2 = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.myProgress2);
myProgress2.setProgressDrawable(gradientDrawable);
```

2.

```
ProgressBar myProgress2 = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.myProgress2);

Drawable bgDrawable = myProgress2.getProgressDrawable();
bgDrawable.setColorFilter(Color.BLUE, android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
myProgress2.setProgressDrawable(bgDrawable);
```

Comment: That's great :) Thank you very much @Ahmad

Comment: Hi @Ahmad. I am getting this error:

java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.ClipDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable

Comment: In method 1? Please share xml.

Comment: XML is shared you can see it in question.

Comment: Exception is in this line? 
GradientDrawable gradientDrawable = (GradientDrawable) layerDrawable
    .findDrawableByLayerId(android.R.id.progress);

Comment: I have done this by doing this:   LayerDrawable layerDrawable = (LayerDrawable) getResources()
                .getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_horizontal_bar);
        ClipDrawable gradientDrawable = (ClipDrawable) layerDrawable
                .findDrawableByLayerId(android.R.id.progress);
        gradientDrawable.setColorFilter((Color.rgb(255, 64, 0)), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OVER);

        pb.setProgressDrawable(layerDrawable);

Comment: Very nice. goood.